# Wifi works only after suspend

Tags: networking, wireless, 15.10, suspend

Im dual booting windows 10 and ubuntu 15.10 on my hp g6 1d98dx, everytime i boot into ubuntu enable wifi is greyed out and there is a hardblock on the wifi. After i suspend then wake my laptop again its gone and wifi works normally, i would like to not have to suspend first everytime i boot into ubuntu. 
Thank you in advance, im open to any suggestions.

Output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`:

```
07:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT5390 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe [1814:5390]
    DeviceName: Ralink 5390GN 802.11b/g/n 1x1 WiFi Adapter
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company U98Z077.00 Half-size Mini PCIe Card [103c:1636]
```

[Wireless info after wake from suspend, with wifi working](https://www.dropbox.com/s/juiw8onx8x97oqi/wireless-info.txt?dl=0)

Comment: The dropbox link is dead.